# Log4j2 PatternLayout format a map value as date

Tags: java, log4j2

with log4j2 I am using MapMessage.
Within the map, I have a key that has a date as value.
Is there a way to display this date in a certain format when using PatternLayout pattern as is the case with LogEvent date ?

For example is there a way to format "myDate" in a format like the one used for %d:
`<PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] ... %map{myDate} %n"/>` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box there is no way to provide formatting information. Basically you have a few choices:

1. Extend MapMessage to customize the formatting of the date field(s) as you desire.
2. Create a custom PatternConverter where you would code something like %myDate{"MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss,SSS", $${map:myDate}}
3. Provide a pull request for [LOG4J2-2841](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2841) to enhance the PatternConverter to access a second parameter with the date value. This would allow something like %myDate{"MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss,SSS", $${map:myDate}}

If you were going to implement item 2 you might as well do item 3 as the work is almost the same.